# How to convert single row to [2*2] dimensional rows

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

Question is :

How to convert single row with four columns to 2*2 dimensional row----------

| Ram 1000 Sita 2000 |
| --- |

Result should be :

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Ram | 1000 |
| Sita | 2000 |

Expecting answers both in SQL and Informatica powercentre

Comment: In SQL it is a basic union: `select c1, c2 from t union all select c3, c4 from t`. Add aliases for column names.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please review your question, show what you've tried so far and indicate what you struggle with. Don't post quiz-like questions for others - try rather to share your problem. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more advice.